# Which certificate do I add to the trusted store in order to add my device certificate to the trusted store?

Tags: vpn, ssl, certificates

I am troubleshooting an issue with my VPN client which lists the troubleshooting steps at https://kb.pulsesecure.net/articles/Pulse_Secure_Article/KB40200.

These instructions just use an ambiguous foo.crt. What certificate do I need to be adding to add my device cert to the trusted store per this article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why do you need to trust a root CA

Certificates just say that something is trusted according to an entity (can be itself).

For example, Stack Overflow uses the following certificate chain:

[image]

The problem is how do you know to trust the Root CA cert? In browsers these are preset (either in the OS or as a local store in the browser)

## How this applies to your VPN

For your VPN you need to manually install the Root CA for the VPN, as the VPN CA will not be pre-installed into your OS.

If your CA is on the VPN server you should be able to get the cert from the VPN server by following these instructions: https://kb.pulsesecure.net/articles/Pulse_Secure_Article/KB40278/?l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle

If you use your own CA you can use it instead.

Comment: Darn. I'll have to go to my network admins for this as I don't have access to the admin panel.

Comment: https://kb.pulsesecure.net/pkb_mobile#article/l:en_US/kA1f1000000WzcQCAS/r may get you the cert